# How do I make a class that when triggered (by :hover) it triggers another class(es)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to to make a table so that when I hover the top cell of the table (th) it changes the background color of all the cells below it.

What I want is to when you hover over the cell "fruit" the background color of all cells below it to have a green background and a white text color.

```css
/*this next part is in a external css document*/

th.topcell {
  color: black;
  background-color: blue;
}

tr.item {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  color: black;
}

th.topcell:hover.item {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th class="topcell">fruit</th>
  </thead>

  <tr>
    <td class="item">banana</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="item">orange</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="item">apple</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Does the table have more than one column in a real example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) for this, but note that you're missing the `tr` in your `thead` as well as a `tbody`. For example, `thead:has(th.topcell:hover) + tbody tr td.item` :

```css
/*this next part is in a external css document*/

th.topcell {
  color: black;
  background-color: blue;
}

tr.item {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  color: black;
}

thead:has(th.topcell:hover) + tbody tr td.item {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="topcell">fruit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="item">banana</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="item">orange</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="item">apple</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```